# AWS S3 TransferManager and CannedAcl settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does `TransferManager` support setting `CannedAcl` when making calls to `copy` and `uploadDirectory`? If the support does not exist, then I am thinking of setting the canned acls using `s3Client.setObjectAcl` after `uploadDirectory/copy` operations. Can someone suggest a better way?

I could see that `PutObjectRequest` and `InitiateMultipartUploadRequest` support `CannedAcl` parameters.